# What could prevent PostOpen code to run when openin with @dialogbox?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus-formula

What could prevent PostOpen code to run, when the form is opened with @dialogbox ?

Users using the **Basic** version of Notes 8.5.1 get the code running, I got 2 computers with Release 8.5.1 **Standard** version (also 8.5.3) don't.

I got a form with

```
Sub Postopen(Source As Notesuidocument)
    Msgbox "hello postopen"
End Sub
```

In an other form I have a @formula hotspot

```
@DialogBox( "dlgForm" ; [NoNewFields] :[AutoHorzFit] : [SizeToTable] ; "some text" )
```

Except this i didn't notice anything strange on the two computers that don't run postopen.

If no reason exists, what do you suggest? Removing bookmark (no success), resetting Notes.ini, reinstall Notes ?

Comment: Also tried lotus script workspace.DialogBox: the same. Found a 8.5.2 Standard version that run the code. So this has nothing to do with basic / standard. Also tried without [NoNewFields], the same.

Comment: "Prohibe"? "when @dialogbox the form?" <- when it ... what? "\"evident\"" -> why the air quotes?

Comment: I'm surprised that a MsgBox would ever work in a form displayed through @DialogBox. I thought that was not supported.

Comment: I'm with Richard. You have a dialog open, so Notes wouldn't be able open a dialog for a dialog. It's a recipe for memory overload to allow dialogs to open dialogs.

Comment: The code don't run, even without msgbox, I used msgbox 1as an example, in fact I compute fields.

Comment: Richard David, help me to remember! I think the limitation of "1 layer UI" has been remove in Rnext, in the same time they increased the number of windows open simultaneously. If I'm wrong, then it's in Notes7. For sure the limit is now 4 recursed dlgbox: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21090956

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPR# TGUZ8N6L54 V90: Events of a form shown in a dialogbox in Notes Client don't fire if Designer Client is open.
Msgbox from a dialogbox should not be a problem -- that's not the issue.

Comment: Whaou! That seems to be the answer, thanks a lot. I'll test after closing designer.

Comment: I checked at Client location. Thank you Andre! To be more precise: If the designer is opened first THEN the client it doesn't work, if the client if opened first even if designer is opened after it still works!

Answer (score 0):

So far I know, the event PostOpen always run even if you are opening the form as a dialog box. Maybe, if you want to test it, instead use `MsgBox`, use:

```
Sub Postopen(Source As Notesuidocument)
    Print "Here's PostOpen!"
End Sub
```

The text will be on the status bar

[image]

Comment: The same, I don't see the print.

Comment: Are you sure that you're opening the right form? Another possibility is that you have two form with the same name/alias.